# Servlet 3.0 async feature and server side push

Tags: jakarta-ee, asynchronous, comet, servlet-3.0, atmosphere

I am looking for some api which actually pushes data to the client. Right now I am using atmosphere with long polling to achieve this. I am using Glassfish 3.1.2 with comet enabled.

Later I heard about Servlet 3.0's async feature. Then I tried to figure whether I can use it to replace atmosphere or not.

The idea is to have a Servlet which upon receiving requests will put them in a List which is in the application scope. Then later after some indefinite time I receive another request which will then iterate through the List and sends response to the clients.

I wrote the first Servlet which receives requests and puts the AsyncContext in the application scope's list. Then I checked whether the AsyncContext is being created or not. I wrote an ajax call which actually hits the url. The ajax request timed out/died after 30 seconds. Then later I tried to set the timeout of AsyncContext and have set it to a negative value so that the timeout will never happen. Later I understood that setTimeOut(int) on AsyncContext is for a different purpose. Now I cannot set the time out to be something very huge as I don't know how many hours or days it will take to send the response.

Then I thought to set the request timeout to some indefinite. But I don't know how to do this.

The same can be achieved in atmosphere using resource.suspend() which suspends the request for indefinite time.

If I cannot use async feature of Servlet 3.0 for this then what is the purpose of it?

What I understood about this feature is, if a request is waiting for some resource say a jdbc connection then the request is placed in a queue and the the thread is returned back to the thread pool so that the thread will be available to serve other requests. [This link](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/asynchronous_support_in_servlet_3) actually starts an async process and passes the object to a Runnable and exits the doGet method. If in case the Runnable takes time to serve the request because of waiting for some resource then the thread is put back in the thread pool and recycled. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is right then if the request exceeds the maximum time waiting for the resource, it will time out and some exception will be sent to the client. How to set the timeout to indefinite programatically and achieve server side push without atmosphere.

Many documentations says that asynchronous servlets can be used to push data to the clients. Where all clients use long polling and if asynchronous is not supported by the server one thread should be allotted for every request which will drain all threads and use lot of memory. If asynchronous is supported all requests will be queued and threads will be free to server other requests. The link [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Continuations) explains the same. But I don't see any technique to suspend a request until we receive an event and not timeout. How frameworks like atmosphere try manage to suspend a request? I think if a http request can be suspended in servlet 3.0 then we don't need any frameworks like atmospehre. Even long polling should be fine instead of web sockets because threads will not be attached to the request always according to servlet 3.0 async feature.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. After little debugging the atmosphere's suspend() method I came to know that suspend() method will not suspend the http request for indefinite time. It suspends the http request till the session timeout expires because there is not meaning in session is expired and still the request is queued.

Now what I want to do is replace atmosphere framework and use servlet 3.0's asynchronous feature.

A client will send a request. In my servlet I will initiate a asyncStart(req,res) and then set it's timeout to the session timeout. Meanwhile if an event occurs, in the Runnable I will commit the response. Then the client will make another request.

Here is my sample code

```
AsyncContext actxt = request.startAsync(request, response);
actxt.setTimeout(request.getMaxInactiveInterval());
executor.execute(new MyService(actxt));
```

Then I will create my own event bus using Observer pattern. MyService class will implement an event handler. Sometime later the event will be fired and all the instances of MySevice will receive this event and will commit the response.

Please let me know if my approach is right or not, or if the approach can me improved.